how to change data-v-date in vuetify datepicker?
I am using DayjsAdapter in my vuetify datepicker and my issue is that

as you can seee data-v-date is no ISO string local time but on default adapter it has a generic one like '2024-02-04'  I am having hard time to discover a way to parse this iso string in data-v-date to normal one
I tried extending dayjsAdapter and use format method on it but it wasnt working

Does it need to be formatted in the DOM for some reason?  In script code, ISO date string can be fed into Date constructor, so where date = '2024-06-13T22:00:00.000Z', get date object with new Date(date).  From there, you can use whatever date functions are necessary to format the date as required.

yes I agree but I need it to be formatted in the DOM like 2024-06-14 not 2024-06-13T22:00:00.000Z because i need this attribute to then pin it to my behave tests in python,

The problem lies in this dayjs adapter because luxon adapter and default adapter are working fine and are not converting this data-v-date to iso string
